# Получение координат объекта в Godot

Tags: координаты, godot

Как можно получить координаты KinematicBody объекта на сцене?

Answer (score 1):

Ну сморти.

```
extends KinematicBody2D
var pos = Vector2() #Создаём переменную у которой есть 'x' и 'y' значения

func _ready():
   pos.x = global_position.x #Передаём значение 'x' переменной
   pos.y = global_position.y #Передаём значение 'y' переменной
   print (pos) #Выводим позицию, можно ещё так: print (global_position)
```

Если хотите вывести определённое значение, например, положение по оси 'x':

```
   print (pos.x)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
global_transform.origin # this hold the global position of the Spatial object.
```